# how to display side bar panel in gmail using javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, css, plugins

I am going to display plugin for firefox and google chrome. i know that all this plugins are developed using javascript and CSS but i donnot know how to display sidebar panel for example facebook chat panel.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For information on how to write a Chrome extension, see the Chrome Extension docs.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html

For information on how to write a Firefox extension, see the Firefox Extension docs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions

In Chrome, for example, you'll need to insert a content script on the page you wish to display other information beyond what's already displayed. For more detail, see here:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html